# each() and resize() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Below is the code I wrote.

```
let thumbHeight =
  $('.content').each(function () {
    let thumbWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).height(thumbWidth * 0.666)
  });

thumbHeight;
$(window).on('resize', thumbHeight);
```

But it doesn't work when resizing the window. There's only an error message. What should I do?

```
Uncaught TypeError: ((S.event.special[o.origType] || {}).handle || o.handler).apply is not a function
    at dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
    at v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)
```

Comment: thumbHeight is not a function, you need to wrap it in a function to be able to use it as an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the help of two people : @MarkBaijens, @yainspan

```
let thumbHeight = function () {
    $('.content').each(function () {
    let thumbWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).height(thumbWidth * 0.666)
  });
}

thumbHeight();
$(window).resize(thumbHeight);
```

Thanks a lot!